# How to use get resouce such as SolidBrush reference in code on windows8 metro platform

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, windows-8, brush, microsoft-metro

We could use this code  `(Brush)this.FindResource("key")` to get the Brush reference in wpf,   how to do the same in windows8 metro?

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
Resource.tryGetValue(out object,key);
```

Should work.